# How to store 2 of the same item in a dictionary

Tags: vb.net

I need to store the same item twice in a dictionary because say I have this sentence: 'Hi Example Test Hi' This should output 1, 2, 3, 1 as it needs to store the initial position with the word. Here is the code I have so far:

```
If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(userInput.Text, "^[a-zA-Z\s]+$") Then

        Dim userString As String = userInput.Text 'Refers to the textbox's text.
        Dim count As Integer 'Declares the count variable, which will be added to the dictionary as the word's position.
        Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) 'Declares the dictionary I will iterate through in the future.
        Dim d2 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        Dim wordString = userString.ToLower().Split(" "c) 'Puts the input into lower case and splits it apart by detecting each space after each word.

        For Each word In wordString

            If (d.ContainsKey(word)) Then

            Else
                d.Add(word, count) 'Adds each word to the dictionary along with the position.
                count = count + 1 'Adds to the count variable to iterate through the dictionary.
            End If
        Next

        For Each de In d
            For Each dee In d2
                output.Text &= de.Value + 1 & ", " & dee.Value + 1 & ", " & Environment.NewLine 'Gathers each word from the dictionary, referencing it by using 'de' and retrieving the key and value.
            Next
        Next

    Else

        MessageBox.Show("Your Sentence Is Invalid, It Must Only Contains Letters.") 'Displays a message if the sentence they inputted is invalid.

    End If
```

thanks,

Matt

Comment: Please name your variables better.. This is so difficult to read when you use `d`, `d2`, `de`, `dee`.

Comment: I think a dictionary isn't suitable for your task, because its meant to store a key value pair just once, i would suggest using a custom class list to store the word its count and positions...

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
Dim userString As String = "Hi Example Test Hi"
Dim count As Integer = 1 'Declares the count variable, which will be added to the dictionary as the word's position.
Dim d As New List(Of WordCountPos) 'Declares the dictionary I will iterate through in the future.
Dim wordString = userString.ToLower().Split(" "c) 'Puts the input into lower case and splits it apart by detecting each space after each word.

For Each word In wordString

    If d.FindIndex(Function(x) String.Equals(x.Word, word)) <> -1 Then

        d.Find(Function(x) String.Equals(x.Word, word)).Positions.Add(count)

    Else

        d.Add(New WordCountPos(word, 1, New List(Of Integer)({count}))) 'Adds each word to the dictionary along with the position

    End If

    count = count + 1 'Adds to the count variable to iterate through the dictionary.

Next

Dim output As String = ""
For Each de In d
    output = String.Concat(output, Environment.NewLine, "Word: ", de.Word, " Count: ", de.Count, ", Positions:", String.Join("|", de.Positions.ToArray))
Next
Console.WriteLine(output)
```

Class:

```
Public Class WordCountPos

    Public Sub New(w As String, c As String, pos As List(Of Integer))

        Me.wcp_w = w
        Me.wcp_c = c
        Me.wcp_pos = pos

    End Sub

    Private wcp_w As String
    Public Property Word() As String
        Get
            Return wcp_w
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            wcp_w = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private wcp_c As Integer
    Public Property Count() As Integer
        Get
            Return wcp_c
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            wcp_c = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private wcp_pos As List(Of Integer)
    Public Property Positions() As List(Of Integer)
        Get
            Return wcp_pos
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Integer))
            wcp_pos = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```